# KMeans clustering to help label Multi-class Supervised model

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, k-means

**EDITED:**
Is it accepted practice to be able to use a KMeans clustering algorithm to help label data fed into a supervised model? (Unsupervised --feeds-> supervised)?

The reason being, relabeling millions of records is not possible and it is a class imbalance problem, where that historical minority class is very useful.

I feel like this is a reinforcement learning problem, but do not know enough about it to say so.

If none of the above, what is a good approach for an imbalanced fraud detection model? Where Precision and recall are better measures than Accuracy.

Comment: K-means clustering is used for unsupervised learning. In this case, you seem to have 3 classes and their actual labels for each case: thus the task might be more suited for multi-class supervised learning.
With the multi-class classification model set up, yes you can predict future cases with the model and possibly block calls.

Comment: I have edited the question, based on it not being a good one. What I am failing to understand is how KMeans would 'expose' the fraud classes through the model, or any other classes that may exist. Since K must be known before?

Comment: IMO, clustering is not likely to expose the fraud class. What clustering is doing is it divides your dataset into similar clusters according to the data. Fraudsters are likely to behave the same way as others and thus the fraud cases are likely to be mixed with non-clusters and be divided into clusters where other behaviours defer, e.g. you may have a cluster of high vs low withdrawals, instead of the fraud vs. non-fraud that you're hoping for. However, the high vs low withdrawal (the result from clustering) can be later used as inputs for a Classification tasks, as explained by @Anony-Mousse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

k-means will not 'label' points for you.

Clustering is not classification.

It's a much harder problem. Most of the time, you get bad results!

So rather than trying to automate this, use clustering to understand your data. Try to derive some rules to identify e.g. different kind of fraud. But **never assume the clusters are all good** (because they never are *all* good).